# Do we have any equivalent function in SQL SERVER for VAL() function of MS Access?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access

I have got a problem while running the code Access Query directly in sql server which contains `VAL([CoLUMN_NAME])`. After googling alot I found a `CAST(COLUMN AS DATATYPE)` to replace `VAL()`.

But When that column is Text type and if we write `VAL([COLUMN_NAME])` we are getting only the number part from that text. For Example the column has this value 45-A45 and used `VAL([COLUMN_NAME])` we will get only "4545".

If we want to achive this in SQL SERVER how to do ?

Answer (score 9):

Val is just the numbers to the left of a string, so you could start with something very roughly like:

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN Patindex('%[^0-9]%', table_1.atext) > 0 THEN Cast( 
         LEFT(table_1.atext, Patindex('%[^0-9]%', table_1.atext) - 1) AS INT) 
         ELSE 0 
       END AS Val 
FROM   table_1;
```

This would return 45 instead of "45 dozen", but needs to be much improved to return 45 instead of "45".

**Edit re comments**

@Andriy M's solution (below) works exactly like Val, as far as I can tell.

```
  SELECT CAST(LEFT(table_1.atext, Patindex('%[^0-9]%', table_1.atext + 'x') - 1) 
  AS INT) AS Val from table_1
```

Edit #2

Table from MS Access:

```
AText   Val(Atext)  
45 dozen    45
ABC 45      0
45_ABC      45
45 ABC 34   45
45          45
ABC         0
```

Using @Andriy M's solution you get exactly the same result.

**I have since found that @GMastros has a better solution**

```
CAST(LEFT(atext, Patindex('%[^-.0-9]%', atext + 'x') - 1) AS Float) AS Val
```

> Note that I changed the search pattern to include the negative sign
>   and a decimal separator. I also changed the data type for the cast to
>   a float. Val returns a vb6 double, which is the same as a SQL Server
>   float. -- G. Mastros

Comment: Not much, perhaps. `ELSE CAST(table_1.atext AS int)` might do. On the other hand, something like `CAST(LEFT(table_1.atext, Patindex('%[^0-9]%', table_1.atext + 'x') - 1) AS INT) AS Val` (i.e. without CASE at all) might do as well.

Comment: @AndriyM Great idea! And that would work with a purely character value as well, would it not?

Comment: I believe it would. In the sense that it would simply evaluate to 0. I'm not sure, though, if either your version or mine is an exact equivalent of the VAL() described by the OP. I mean, their example, `'45-A45' -> 4545`, seems to suggest different logic. Still, I find it more confusing. For instance, it is not clear whether `.` should be interpreted as part of a number as well, and if so, how the function would interpret e.g. `'12A.B.34'`.

Comment: No, '45-A45' -> 4545 is not what Val does. ?val("45-A45") = 45. I believe they have expressed the question badly.

Comment: Ah, I see, it's all right then, thanks. (I don't have MS Access, so I couldn't verify.)

Comment: Val("45-A45") = 45, **not** 4545 as you show in your question, therefore I do not see what you mean. There is no way in ordinary Jet/ACE SQL to get 4545 from an actual value "45-A45", you can format a number to *look* like "45-A45" -- `Format(4545,"##-\A##")` and in that case straight sql may return 4545. Regarding matching Val in SQL Server, the line that G Mastros very kindly provided does that. I show in my notes above a table of the result of Val used in MS Access.