# Update Query in SQL Server using Access code

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, format, sql-server-2016-express

What is the corresponding SQL Server code to do this? This was written in Access.

```
UPDATE TableDB SET accountcode = format(val(accountCode),'000.000');
```

The column "accountCode" is a text format. Currently, some are xx.x, xxx, x.xxx, etc. I want all of the values to follow the **xxx.xxx** format, with zeros in the right locations. For example, 45.3 would be 045.300, 62.04 would be 062.040, etc

Thanks

Comment: Add the tag for the specific SQL Server version you're using.

Comment: Done- it's SQL Server 2016 express

Comment: What about that statement won't work in SQLServer? Did you try it? If Val function is the issue, review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14475799/do-we-have-any-equivalent-function-in-sql-server-for-val-function-of-ms-access

Comment: Yes, val is not a built-in function name for SQL Server. I'll check out your link, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all `accountcode` values adhere to your sample data format, you should be able to update the values with this query:

```
WITH with_zero_padded AS (
    SELECT
          accountcode
        , '000' + accountcode + '000' AS zero_padded_accountcode
    FROM dbo.TableDB
)
UPDATE with_zero_padded
SET accountcode = LEFT(STUFF(zero_padded_accountcode, 1, CHARINDEX('.', zero_padded_accountcode)-4, ''), 7)
FROM with_zero_padded;
```

Comment: The format is spot-on, however now I have many nulls which shouldn't be the case. I believe the nulls are for when the value is a whole number with no period. For example, '100' returns as NULL which I don't want, while '100.1' returns '100.100' which is what I want.

If I can't figure out the coding solution, I may just use Excel to force a "." after whole numbers, then run this code.